# advance pointer without reading

Tags: c, linux, file-descriptor

How do you advance the pointer position for a file without actually reading them.

I ran into the situation in which I needed to discard the first X bytes in the file and then start reading. (In case, you are curious, WAV file discard the header of 44 bytes).

I ended up reading them just to advance the pointer.

```
int input_fd;

input_fd = open("sample.wav", O_RDONLY);
assert(input_fd !=-1 );

int dummy[44];

read(input_fd,dummy,44);
```

Is there a less expensive way of doing this?

Comment: Notice that `assert` is *not* the correct way to handle runtime errors! the condition of `assert` *must not ever fail*; its presence or absence is not supposed to change the behaviour of your program.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`lseek()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/lseek.2.html) system call.

```
lseek(input_fd, 44, SEEK_CUR);
```